# Retornar datos nulos de una subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Estoy trabajando con MySQL haciendo una lista de top 100 de palabras clave asociadas a artículos científicos. La subquery, básicamente proporciona el top 100 de palabras clave junto con el número de veces que aparecen **a nivel mundial**.

Ahora, lo que yo quiero es filtrar por país de esas 100 palabras clave pero con una condición: si dicho país no ha trabajado con dichas palabras clave, quiero que la consulta retorne un 0 en dicha fila y que **no la omita**. Es decir, la consulta también debe retornar 100 filas.

***Consulta actual***

```
SELECT  tAIK.INDEX_KEYWORDS, 
        COUNT(*)
FROM tARTICLE tA, tARTICLE_tCOUNTRIES tAC, tARTICLE_tINDEX_KEYWORDS tAIK
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT INDEX_KEYWORDS,
            COUNT(*)
    FROM tARTICLE tA, tARTICLE_tINDEX_KEYWORDS tAIK
    WHERE tAIK.DOI = tA.DOI
    GROUP BY INDEX_KEYWORDS
    ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, INDEX_KEYWORDS
    LIMIT 100) AUX -- Subquery
ON tAIK.INDEX_KEYWORDS = AUX.INDEX_KEYWORDS
WHERE tA.DOI = tAIK.DOI
AND tA.DOI = tAC.DOI 
AND tAC.COUNTRY = "Canada"
GROUP BY tAIK.INDEX_KEYWORDS
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, tAIK.INDEX_KEYWORDS;
```

***Referencias***

He indagado por mi cuenta viendo funciones como [ISNULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull), [CASE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) o [COALESCE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) pero no me sirven. También he probado a utilizar, en vez del INNER JOIN un RIGHT JOIN basándome en la [representación gráfica de los JOINS en SQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQ5XP.png).

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Y como son los resultados de tu consulta, en el `count(*)` de la consulta padre que resultado te da, quiero suponer que 1 o el resultado de tu subconsulta 100?

Comment: El problema puede estar en que de esas 100 palabras principales(subquery) pueda haber alguna que no esté utilizada en algún artículo del país que buscas, quizá por eso no te da un resultado de 100, utiliza un `LEFT JOIN` solo con `AUX`

Comment: @Hammerffall BK Sí, la consulta padre al final puede retornar un número de filas comprendido entre 0 y 100. Entiendo perfectamente cual es el motivo por el que no retorna las 100 filas. Ahora, respecto al `LEFT JOIN`, ¿por qué un `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: Perdón, por regla general siempre suelo dejar a los padres a la izquierda para usar `LEFT JOIN` dando prioridad a las tablas a la izquierda, en este caso tu tabla padre son las palabras. Has tratado que en vez de `COUNT(*)` un `COUNT(tAIK.INDEX_KEYWORDS)`, debido a que haces un conteo sobre * toma en cuenta las columnas, cuando deberías de tomar las columnas que pueden a llegar a ser nulas(con `RIGHT JOIN`)